# How to resize a vector to a specific length?

Tags: vectors

I have a 3D vector `u` defined through two points `A (0/2/0)` and `B (3/3/3)`.

```
u        = [3/1/3]  
u.length = sqrt(3²+1²+3²) = 4.24...
```

How can I get a new vector `v` with `v.length = 1.5` which has the same origin `A` and direction as `u`?

Comment: Divide your vector by its length and multiply by 1.5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general, if you have a vector $\bf v$, and you want another vector in the same direction, with a given length $L$, then the vector: $${\bf u} = \frac{L}{\|{\bf v}\|} {\bf v}$$
does the job, because: $$\left\|{\bf u} \right\| = \left\| \frac{L}{\|{\bf v}\|} {\bf v} \right\| = \frac{L}{\|{\bf v}\|} \|{\bf v}\| = L $$

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add in the coördinates of the origin.

$\left[{9\over{2\sqrt {19}}}/{{3+4\sqrt {19}}\over{2\sqrt {19}}}/{9\over{2\sqrt {19}}}\right]$